# Python setuptools help on windows. Dll dependencies not identified

Tags: dll, python-3.6, setuptools

I wrote a pybind11 wrapper over a shared c++ library (.dll) on Windows.
I wanted to make a distributable package using setuptools.

I wrote a setup.py file and it generated the pyd file for the wrapper.
But when I try to run a script which imports the wrapper package python crashes.

It only succeeds only if I place all the dll dependencies in the script folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution to the above problem.
I created an **init**.py file which adds the DLL directory in the beginning of the environment path variable.